# Google cloud storage on react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage, expo

I have a project needs to store profile photos on google cloud storage. I got a signed URL from our API, and I upload the image with:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT", signedURL, true);
xhr.onload = () => {
  const status = xhr.status;
  if (status === 200) {
    console.log("ok");
  } else {
    console.log("Something went wrong!", status);
  }
};

xhr.onerror = () => {
  console.log("......Something went wrong!")
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/octet-stream");

const fileBuffer = base64.toByteArray(data)
xhr.send(fileBuffer);
```

To render image on React Native, I am using in this way:

`<Image source={{uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucketname/myfile.jpg'}} />`,

I changed the bucket to Public Access (add member `allUsers` to Storage Object Viewer).

The result is, from the dashboard, [image] I click `Public to internet` and `Link URL`, they return two different images, which `Public to internet` always the first image and `Link URL` is always the latest uploaded. Any idea how to fix this or what is the correct way to show the image?

Besides, I also need to upload and review videos and documents, is that possible to render on react native, even if the bucket has to be private?

Comment: Sorry, as for the two links return different images because the account does not have enough permissions. But the image also not be updated since the cache issue. so the solution is `<Image source={{uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucketname/myfile.jpg?${Math.random()}'}} />`

Comment: I still have no idea if the mobile can access the video or documents if the bucket is private, is there a solution for that?

Comment: You might find useful [this documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage)